# Facebook app linking with iOS

Tags: ios, applinks

My requirement is to create simple Facebook app linking to open installed app / redirect to app store link. I have followed instructions on below link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking

I am able to create link immediately but problem is when I click on created custom URL, it is always redirecting to App Store link and not opening already installed app on the device. Strange thing is in browser if I provide "mytravelapp://" (one of field in above instructions on Facebook developer account) it's opening installed app. But do not know why on created app link URL, installed app is not getting launched and always redirecting to App Store link.

Any help would be appreciated, though it looks quite simple.

Comment: i have the same issue ,, i think the problem is with iOS 9 ,, because on iOS 8 its working 
have you figure out the solution ?

Comment: They've updated the facebook app, which now allows it to open urischemes :)

Answer (score 2):

Following.. It seems like Facebook changed the way app linking is working in their new in-app browser. What i've found out is that the in-app browser, only opens system custom URI schemes.